# Need regx for converting all the double backslash to single backslash in perl

Tags: perl

I have a string below string i am using regular expression but nothing is working:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
my $var ="\\\\abc\\cde\\pqs\\some";
my $var1 = s/\\/\/;

$var =~ s/$var/$var1/;

print "$var\n";
```

Purpose is all the double backslash need to change with single backslash.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w
use strict;
use warnings;

my $var ="\\\\abc\\cde\\pqs\\some";
$var =~ s|\\{2}|\\|g;

print "$var\n";
```

Answer (score 0):

To replace two blackslashes with one, you can use this simple regular expression:

```
$var =~ s/\\\\/\\/g;
```

This will do the conversation, but the result will probably not what you expected.

I think what you actually tried to do is this:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w

my $demo = "\\\\\\\\abc\\\\cde\\\\pqs\\\\some";
$demo =~ s/(^|[^\\])\\{2}($|[^\\])/$1\\$2/g;
$demo =~ s/(^|[^\\])\\{4}($|[^\\])/$1\\\\$2/g;
print "Result: $demo\n";
```

I think you had an escaped string, containing backlashes, like the following example:

```
\\\\server\\path\\path\\path
```

And you would like to transform it into this:

```
\\server\path\path\path
```

Then you have to use the "two step" regular expression shown in my example above.

---

#### Explanation of the Regular Expresion

First at all, it is a "search/replace" regular expression:

```
s/.../.../g
```

The `g` at the end means "global matching". This actually means, after the first match and replacement, the string is further searched for more matches until all matches were found and replaced. The way how this works, is why the regular expression in my example is probably hand to understand:

If we have a string like this:

```
heeeello
```

And you apply a regular expression like this:

```
s/ee/e/g
```

You actually get this result:

```
hello
```

This, because the `ee` matches several times. In the following example for illustration, I write the matched characters in uppercase:

```
hEEeello  -> hEeello
hEEello   -> hEello
hEEllo    -> hEllo
no match left.
```

This is the reason for the extra bits in my regular expressions. In the first one, I search for places with **exactly 2** backslashes and replace them with one. In the second regular expression I search for places with **exactly 4** backslashes and replace them with two.

Let us have a look at the search part:

```
(^|[^\\])\\{2}($|[^\\])
```

- `(^|[^\\])` This is actually a capturing group `(...|...)`. Actually it matches **either** `^`=the beginning of the text, **or** `[^\\]` *not* a backslash character.
- `\\{2}` This matches exactly `{2}` two backslash characters.
- `($|[^\\])` This is similar to the first group. It means: Match **either** `$` = the end of the text, **or** `[^\\]` = not a backslash character.

The second regular expression is similar, but it uses `\\{4}` to match exactly four backslashes.

This `[^\\]` match *not* a backslash character parts are necessary to avoid the behaviour shown in the "hello" example above.

This example string:

```
\\\\\\\\\\\\\a
```

Simple wouldn't match.

Comment: Hi Flovdis ..  can you please  explain your regx if possible  because i am not able to get it .It will be really help full for me. thanks

Comment: Ok, edited the answer with an additional explanation.

Comment: I fixed a problem. It should be (?= and not (?:

Comment: Thanks a Lot Flovdis for such a nice explanation.It helps me a lot :)

Answer (score 0):

You're assigning a regex to `$var1` and then put that into the replacement part of another regex - This can't work. Besides, the regex needs to use the `g` modifier to replace all matches, not only the first one.

```
use strict;
use warnings;
my $var ="\\\\abc\\cde\\pqs\\some";
$var =~ s/\\\\/\\/g;

print "$var\n";
```

Answer (score 0):

```
use strict;
use warnings;
my $var = "\\\\abc\\cde\\pqs\\some";

$var =~ s/\\{2}/\\/g;

print "$var\n";
```

Answer (score 0):

There is actually a more complex but simpler solution:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w

my $demo = "\\\\\\\\abc\\\\cde\\\\pqs\\\\some";
$demo =~ s/(?:^|[^\\])(\\+)(?:$|[^\\])/{'\\' x (length("$1")\/2)}/ge;
print "Result: $demo\n";
```

This is using an expression in the replacement section which just divides the number of found backslash characters by 2.